# Не приходит смс Firebase auth phone number

Tags: android, firebase, аутентификация

Использую Firebase auth phone number, по тестовым номерам аутентификация проходит успешно, а вот на реальный номере телефона (оператор Vodafone Украина) смс с кодом не приходит. В чем может быть дело?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText phoneNumberEditText;
private EditText verificationCodeEditText;
private Button enterCodeButton;
private Button getVerificationCodeButton;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseFirestore database;
private String codeSent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    bindView();
    setListeners();
}

private void bindView() {
    phoneNumberEditText = findViewById(R.id.phone_edit_text);
    verificationCodeEditText = findViewById(R.id.code_edit_text);
    enterCodeButton = findViewById(R.id.button_enter_code);
    getVerificationCodeButton = findViewById(R.id.button_get_code);
}

private void setListeners() {
    enterCodeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    getVerificationCodeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    if (view.getId() == R.id.button_enter_code) {
        String verificationCode = verificationCodeEditText.getText().toString();
        verifySignInCode(verificationCode);

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button_get_code) {
        String phoneNumber = phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString();

        sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);
    }
}

private void verifySignInCode(String verificationCode) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = null;
    try {
        credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codeSent, verificationCode);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        verificationCodeEditText.setError("Invalid code");
        phoneNumberEditText.requestFocus();
    }

}

private void sendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber) {

    if (phoneNumber.isEmpty()) {
        phoneNumberEditText.setError("Phone number is required");
        phoneNumberEditText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (phoneNumber.length() < 10) {
        phoneNumberEditText.setError("Please enter a valid phone");
        phoneNumberEditText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this,
            mCallbacks);

}


private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        final FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();

                        updateUI(user);

                    } else {

                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}


private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}



PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        codeSent = s;
    }
};
```

}

**UPDATE:**
Установил приложение на таблетку(Андроид 6.0) ввел номер телефона на который не приходил код, и код пришел на телефон. В итоге заметил, что на телефоне(Андроид 7.0) не работает `PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks` и в связи с этим кидает `IllegalArgumentException` этот метод провайдера `PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codeSent, verificationCode)`, из-за того что `codeSent == null`. Почему такое происходит не понятно, на эмуляторах и таблетке такой проблемы нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, банально обновив Google сервисы. Смс приходит и все нормально работает.